# A required file could not be downloaded while installing SQL Server 2022 Express / SQL 2019 DEV

Tags: sql-server

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5fGk.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rLUu.png)I'm facing this error when trying to install SQL 2022 Server Express. The same error I have been facing when installing SQL Server 2019 DEV also.
I have tried to run this 2 commands in Powershell as admin:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
```

and still I'm facing the same error.
[SchUseStrongCrypto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tb0G.png).
I don't know what else to try.

Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Express and Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

P.S: I can't upload photos, so it's uploaded as link but I have followed everything in the: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319
Dword key: SchUseStrongCrypto
Value 1